# Validation Methods and Return Values - Exceptions vs Model State vs Bool

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

I have rules that requires Data Validation in my App that I would typically validate in three different ways and i'm unsure how I should validate and return information to the controller to display to the user.

I am adding a house object to a street object. There are 3 rules to follow.

**Rule 1. The House number must between 0-10**

*Method: Data Annotation / Validation with Model State*

I would typically validate this rule with a simple data annotation in the model

```
[Range(0,10, ErrorMessage = "Blah blah blah")]
```

And then do a ModelState.IsValid check in the controller.

**Rule 2. The Housenumber and Street name combination must be unique**

*Method: Fluent API / Will throw SqlException*

I would normally implement this rules with Fluent API as follows

```
       builder.Entity<Street>(b =>
        {
            b.HasIndex(e => new { e.HouseNumber, e.StreetName }).IsUnique();
        });
```

I would expect this to throw an exception when i tried to add it to the database, that I would catch in the Service Layer.

**Rule 3 - The Street cant contain more than 10 houses**

*Method: Service Layer check, and throw exception or return false*

I would normally have my controller call a service layer, that would check the business rules before calling the repository to save the data. If it failed a rule it would either throw an exception.

```
throw new CreateHouseException("Street has reached maximum capacity");
```

or simply have the method return false.

**The rest of it**

My my views / viewModels are all set up to return a Status Message if needed with information the the user.

All this seems very disjointed with business rule validation happening in three ways in three locations.

1. Controller checks Model State
2. Service Layer checks manually coded rules
3. Database throws SqlException when fluent API set up was violated

I feel like I should be consolidating my Validation to one location and i'm sure this should be done in the service layer. I've done some research and am weighing up the following points

1. Some have said I should not pass the Model State to the Service layer as this is bad for separation of concerns and doesn't help with the exception throw by the Fluent API validation.
2. Throwing too many exceptions for everything from the service layer to the controller seems an easy fix but messy
3. The fluent API validation throws an exception so I must process and combine Model State and these exceptions somehow.

I know some of this may be personal preference. But how would you consolidate these 3 methods, and how would you return the necessary info to the controller to pass to the view?

Comment: That's how I do it: The service layer / db part expects correct data and will throw an exception if something is not valid (this should not happen). Controller / model state checks user input and returns error messages if input is not valid. Only valid input will be forewarded to service layer. Service layer may provide helpers like "CanAddHouseToStreet()" to be used for validation is controller.

Comment: Would your service layer double validate rules? For example, the Unique composite key in the database. Would you have a check in the service layer that this key didn't exist before saving it? or rely on the database to throw back the exception and just catch it and deal with is appropriately? 

I think i should be limiting service layer validation to thing the modelstate and database validation miss

Comment: In theory: Service layer expect "valid" input, it just has to ensure that invalid input will not be saved - db exceptions are totaly ok for that. Service could expose a "LimitReached()" method to allow the controller to check if it's allowed to add the new item. The problem in this special case: it means one more db query so I think I would use a "try and check exception" approach here.

Comment: Validation is one of those things that really has to be all over the place. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351419/clean-architecture-validation-in-domain-vs-data-persistence-layer/351662#351662).